# I want to add gaussian noise to colour image where the standard deviation of gaussian noise were varied from 0.2 to 2 at 0.2 intervals in openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have tried to separate the colour channels and add noise to each of them and merge them. And succeed to do so. But I want to separate the Y Cr Cb components and then add noise to only Y. Finally merge the components but could not. My code for colour channels:

```
for (int i=0 ; i<3 ; i++){
    Mat noise = Mat(channel[i].size(), CV_64F);    
    normalize(channel[i], result[i], 0.0, 1.0, CV_MINMAX, CV_64F);
    randn(noise, 0, .2);
    result[i] += noise;
    normalize(result[i], result[i], 0.0, 1.0, CV_MINMAX, CV_64F);    
    result[i].convertTo(result[i], CV_32F, 255, 0);
}

merge(result, 3, input);
imwrite("/Users/hossainmdshakhawat/developer/subimg/Noisy/merge.jpg", input);
```

Comment: I can split the Y Cr, and Cb. I can add noise to Y too. But while I am trying to merge I am getting assertion error.

Comment: Read the `assertion Error` and reconfirm if size, type, depth, channels, etc are same for all the constituting layers, it would be helpful if you paste the error statement as well

Comment: OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (mv[i].size == mv[0].size && mv[i].depth() == depth) in merge, file /Users/hossainmdshakhawat/opencv-3.0.0/modules/core/src/convert.cpp, line 950
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /Users/hossainmdshakhawat/opencv-3.0.0/modules/core/src/convert.cpp:950: error: (-215) mv[i].size == mv[0].size && mv[i].depth() == depth in function merge

Comment: Try converting it too 8 bit.